# Select next_id, prev_id, *

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    '' as next_id,
    '' as prev_id,
    u.name,
    u.id,
    t.truck_number,
    p.check_date,
    p.* 
FROM 
         eaglex_crm.pro   p
    JOIN eaglex_crm.truck t ON t.id = p.truck_id
    JOIN eaglex_crm.users u on u.id = p.driver_id
WHERE true
order by u.id, t.id, p.check_date
```

Here's what I'm looking at.
[image: Output]

I'd like to return the next and previous ids from the same list. Please assist if this is possible. Thank you!

Comment: Use LAG / LEAD.

Comment: That's what I was after!